# Calculate average distance between pairs of points without computing full distance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, distance-measure

Suppose I have a set of $N$ points of shape $N \times D$, where $D$ is the dimensionality. I want to compute the average Euclidean distance between all points, as well as additional moments such as the variance, median, and percentile boundaries.

Is there a way to calculate or estimate these quantities without finding the full $N \times N$ distance matrix? I am hoping for a solution that requires less than $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ memory.

Comment: Do you have any a-priory knowledge of the point cloud? I mean thinks like absolute bounding box or if they are clustered or more homogeneously spread?

What language are you working in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in $\mathcal{O}(N)$ time (and memory) using a fast multipole algorithm that can handle nondecaying kernel functions such as the distance function $d(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|$.

The average distance is given by $\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} d(\mathbf{x}_i,\mathbf{x_j})$. The inner sum can be evaluated at each $\mathbf{x}_i,i=1,\ldots,N$ in a total of $\mathcal{O}(N)$ time, and the outer sum over $i$ can also be computed in $\mathcal{O}(N)$ time.

I'd recommend the use of the black-box FMM code here: https://github.com/ruoxi-wang/BBFMM3D.

Answer (score 1):

When calculating averages, you can iterate through all point connections and carry a counter, and the sum of the distances. You can overwrite any individual distance with the new ones. That way your memory footprint is minimal.